# How to determine optimal interval count in a given range?

Tags: c#, algorithm, intervals

I'm trying to determine the optimal solution for this tough problem. I've got a length (let's say 11). So it's a one dimensional space 0-10. Now I've got these intervals with **same** length (let's assume 2 in this example). Now they're randomly distributed (overlapping, or not). Let me draw an example:

```
Situation:

|00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10| <- Space (length = 11)

|-----|       
         |-----|
            |-----|
               |-----|
                  |-----|
                           |-----| <- single interval of length = 2
```

Now the solution needs to find the maximal number of intervals that can fit at once without overlap.

```
The solution is: 4 intervals
```

There are three results of 4 intervals:

```
|00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|

|-----|  |-----|-----|     |-----| <- result 1
|-----|  |-----|  |-----|  |-----| <- result 2
|-----|     |-----|-----|  |-----| <- result 3
```

But there are also two more constraints as well.

1. If there are more results (of best solution, in this case = 4), then the one with the least number of gaps.
2. If there are more results still the one with the highest minimal length of all its spaces. For example the one with spaces (of length) 2 & 3 has minimal length of space = 2, that is better than 1 & 4 where the minimal length of space is only 1.

So the result 2 has 4 "continual" chunks, the other two have only 3 so the refinement is:

```
|00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|

|-----|  |-----------|     |-----| <- result 1
|-----|     |-----------|  |-----| <- result 3
```

Those two got same space distributions between them, so let's take first one.

The result for the input set is:

```
Interval count  : 4
Optimal solution: |-----|  |-----------|     |-----|
```

The algorithm has to work universally for all the space length (not only 11), all interval lengths (interval length is always <= space length) and any number of intervals.

**Update:**

Problematic scenario:

```
|00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|

|-----|  
         |-----| 
            |-----|     
                        |-----|
|-----|
```

Comment: Interesting.  But where is your attempt?

Comment: A good problem, but I don't think it fits well to SO.

Comment: Did you try to come by something and did not succeed? 
Dude, this is not Project Euler.

Comment: My attempt is basically a brutal force :)

Comment: The second constraint is not well defined: what does the "most distance" mean? If you mean the total un-covered length, they are all same for all the solutions with maximal number of intervals.

Comment: I don't know how to exactly describe it. It should be with the one with the biggest spaces. For example if there's one with spaces of 2 & 3 is better then the one with 1 & 4. So it's the one with larger minimal length of "free space" chunks I guess.

Comment: To the poster: do not phrase this is the form of a Challenge, as these are no longer welcome here.  Rephrase your question in the form of something that you need help with.

Comment: Well I never knew there is something like a challenge with capital C. I meant it as a challenge generally a tough problem I need to help with. I can delete the last question, if it helps?

Comment: Already done.  Explain why you need this and post your attempt, brute force or not.

Comment: To those voting to Close this as "Not A Real Question.", Please Explain.  This appears to be a Real Question to me and doe not seem to fit in any of the qualifications for "Not A Real Question."

Comment: I didn't wrote it down. I just know I can do the brutal force solution. The problem is not solving it, but solving it better than via brutal force. Now I know it will take some N of non repetitive combinations of comparisons. I'm working on paper here. I've been able to reduce (on paper = notepad) the comparisons to representing the intervals as binary format, and the XOR between them should yield whether overlap. This is a speed-up, but I would be glad if there was some "known" solution to this problem. As those two suggested below.

Comment: I also agree with a real question. Of course this is a real question. I'm working on a image processing routine, and this small bit is a part of it. Otherwise I don't understand the criteria for the real question either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple dynamic programming problem.

Let the total length be `N` and the length of a task be `L`.

Let `F(T)` be maximum number of tasks that can be selected from the sub interval `(T, N)`, then at each unit time T, there are 3 possibilities:

1. There is no task that starts at T.
2. There is a task that starts at T, but we do not include it in the result set.
3. There is a task that starts at T, and we do include it in the result set.

Case 1 is simple, we just have `F(T) = F(T + 1)`.

In case 2/3, notice that selecting a task that start a `T` means we must reject all tasks that start while this task is running, i.e. between `T` and `T + L`. So we get `F(T) = max(F(T + 1), F(T + L) + 1)`.

Finally, `F(N) = 0`. So you just start from `F(N)` and work your way back to `F(0)`.

**EDIT:** This will give you the maximum number of intervals, but not the set that fulfils your 2 constraints. Your explanation of the constraints is unclear to me, so I'm not sure how to help you there. In particular, I can't tell what constraint 1 means since all the solutions to your example set are apparently equal.

**EDIT 2:** Some further explanation as requested:

Consider your posted example, we have `N = 11` and `L = 2`. There are tasks that start at `T = 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9`. Starting from `F(11) = 0` and working backwards:

- `F(11) = 0`
- `F(10) = F(11) = 0` (Since no task starts at `T = 10`)
- `F(9) = max(F(10), F(11) + 1) = 1`
- ...

Eventually we get to `F(0) = 4`:

```
T   |00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|
F(T)| 4| 3| 3| 3| 3| 2| 2| 1| 1| 1| 0|
```

**EDIT 3:** Well I was curious enough about this that I wrote a solution, so may as well post it. This will give you the set that has the most tasks, with the least number of gaps, and the smallest minimum gap. The output for the examples in the question is:

- `(0, 2) -> (4, 6) -> (6, 8) -> (9, 11)`
- `(0, 2) -> (4, 6) -> (8, 10)`

Obviously, I make no guarantees about correctness! :)

private class Task
    {
        public int Start { get; set; }
        public int Length { get; set; }
        public int End { get { return Start + Length; } }

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("({0:d}, {1:d})", Start, End);
    }
}

private class CacheEntry : IComparable
{
    public int Tasks { get; set; }
    public int Gaps { get; set; }
    public int MinGap { get; set; }
    public Task Task { get; set; }
    public Task NextTask { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as CacheEntry;
        if (Tasks != other.Tasks)
            return Tasks - other.Tasks; // More tasks is better
        if (Gaps != other.Gaps)
            return other.Gaps = Gaps; // Less gaps is better
        return MinGap - other.MinGap; // Larger minimum gap is better
    }
}

private static IList<Task> F(IList<Task> tasks)
{
    var end = tasks.Max(x => x.End);
    var tasksByTime = tasks.ToLookup(x => x.Start);
    var cache = new List<CacheEntry>[end + 1];

    cache[end] = new List<CacheEntry> { new CacheEntry { Tasks = 0, Gaps = 0, MinGap = end + 1 } };

    for (int t = end - 1; t >= 0; t--)
    {
        if (!tasksByTime.Contains(t))
        {
            cache[t] = cache[t + 1];
            continue;
        }

        foreach (var task in tasksByTime[t])
        {
            var oldCEs = cache[t + task.Length];
            var firstOldCE = oldCEs.First();
            var lastOldCE = oldCEs.Last();

            var newCE = new CacheEntry
            {
                Tasks = firstOldCE.Tasks + 1,
                Task = task,
                Gaps = firstOldCE.Gaps,
                MinGap = firstOldCE.MinGap
            };

            // If there is a task that starts at time T + L, then that will always 
            // be the best option for us, as it will have one less Gap than the others
            if (firstOldCE.Task == null || firstOldCE.Task.Start == task.End)
            {
                newCE.NextTask = firstOldCE.Task;
            }
            // Otherwise we want the one that maximises MinGap.
            else
            {
                var ce = oldCEs.OrderBy(x => Math.Min(x.Task.Start - newCE.Task.End, x.MinGap)).Last();
                newCE.NextTask = ce.Task;
                newCE.Gaps++;
                newCE.MinGap = Math.Min(ce.MinGap, ce.Task.Start - task.End);
            }

            var toComp = cache[t] ?? cache[t + 1];
            if (newCE.CompareTo(toComp.First()) < 0)
            {
                cache[t] = toComp;
            }
            else
            {
                var ceList = new List<CacheEntry> { newCE };

                // We need to keep track of all subsolutions X that start on the interval [T, T+L] that
                // have an equal number of tasks and gaps, but a possibly a smaller MinGap. This is
                // because an earlier task may have an even smaller gap to this task.
                int idx = newCE.Task.Start + 1;
                while (idx < newCE.Task.End)
                {
                    toComp = cache[idx];
                    if
                    (
                        newCE.Tasks == toComp.First().Tasks &&
                        newCE.Gaps == toComp.First().Gaps &&
                        newCE.MinGap >= toComp.First().MinGap
                    )
                    {
                        ceList.AddRange(toComp);
                        idx += toComp.First().Task.End;
                    }
                    else
                        idx++;
                }

                cache[t] = ceList;
            }
        }
    }

    var rv = new List<Task>();
    var curr = cache[0].First();
    while (true)
    {
        rv.Add(curr.Task);
        if (curr.NextTask == null) break;
        curr = cache[curr.NextTask.Start].First();
    }

    return rv;
}

public static void Main()
{
    IList<Task> tasks, sol;

    tasks = new List<Task>
    {
        new Task { Start = 0, Length = 2 },
        new Task { Start = 3, Length = 2 },
        new Task { Start = 4, Length = 2 },
        new Task { Start = 5, Length = 2 },
        new Task { Start = 6, Length = 2 },
        new Task { Start = 9, Length = 2 },
    };

    sol = F(tasks);
    foreach (var task in sol)
        Console.Out.WriteLine(task);
    Console.Out.WriteLine();

    tasks = new List<Task>
    {
        new Task { Start = 0, Length = 2 },
        new Task { Start = 3, Length = 2 },
        new Task { Start = 4, Length = 2 },
        new Task { Start = 8, Length = 2 },
    };

    sol = F(tasks);
    foreach (var task in sol)
        Console.Out.WriteLine(task);
    Console.Out.WriteLine();

    tasks = new List<Task>
    {
        new Task { Start = 0, Length = 5 },
        new Task { Start = 6, Length = 5 },
        new Task { Start = 7, Length = 3 },
        new Task { Start = 8, Length = 9 },
        new Task { Start = 19, Length = 1 },
    };

    sol = F(tasks);
    foreach (var task in sol)
        Console.Out.WriteLine(task);
    Console.Out.WriteLine();

    Console.In.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: The time/task implications are confusing me. But even though I  probably need more explanation than this. Can you show me how it will play out? I mean draw a few steps, so I'm able to get what's going on?

Comment: @SmartK8 When I say 'task' I mean one of the intervals in your original question statement. I am using 'time' to denote the point where the interval starts, e.g. you example has tasks that start at times 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 9.

Comment: OK, but can you show me result of few first iterations. For me to catch up with your solution?

Comment: @SmartK8 See updated answer. Now that I think about this some more, I think in the case where all the intervals are the same length, you can just take the greedy approach of starting from the left and taking every task you can. This is because when all the tasks are the same length, you can never get into a situation where taking a task that starts later is better than one that starts earlier.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. Let me try it. Sounds pretty amazing if it works (I mean universally).

Comment: ad constraint 1) The result 3 has 3 gaps between the intervals, the other two solutions have only 2 gaps.

Comment: The sole number (as calculated by algorithm you provided) is a - let's say - phase I., having the actual result set with constraints applied is a phase II. As I'm talking about the image processing, it depends on whether phase I. will be of good enough visual quality or not.

Comment: @SmartK8 Not sure what you mean by "universally", but this approach generalises easily to cater for intervals of different lengths, and finding both the largest number of tasks completed or the highest total space utilised.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much universally :) I've tried you approach, and seems to work very well so far. Is there any chance to somehow reconstruct, or gather the result sets via this algorithm? I think processing the constraints afterwards would be quite easy once the "first generation" results are available.

Comment: @SmartK8 Enumerating all the possible sets of that length is probably not a great plan (there could be lots of them). Instead you can augment the cache that is constructed by `F(T)` to store the other stuff you need to construct your set. For example, in addition to the number of tasks you could also store the start time of the next task, the number of gaps, and the smallest gap.

Comment: Fine, I'll try to check out, if there is a feasible solution using this method. This is so complex (I mean the overall image processing thing), that my brain kinda burned out today from all these complicated subroutines. So excuse me for grasping the things only slowly. I'll let you know, or I'll accept the answer. I think I need to take a rest.

Comment: Fantastic work! One little glitch. I've updated question with a one problematic scenario. It fails on two cases (one I was able to solve by removing duplicate - starting the same - tasks). The second one is something with gaps. My guess is it returns the one with minimal gap, not with highest minimal gap.

Comment: @SmartK8 You can alter it to deal with multiple tasks starting at the same time pretty trivially, just change `ToDictionary()` to `ToLookup()` and `var task = taskByTime[t]` to `foreach (var task in tasksByTime[t]) { ... }`. I really don't understand what "highest minimal gap" means.

Comment: Well as I said. If there are two gaps between intervals. One is length = 2, the other length = 2. So the minimal gap length is 2. This is better then when the gaps are of lengths 1 and 3. Checkout the problematic scenario. Your solution returns intervals starting at 0, 3, 8.. but that solution has minimal gap length = 1. While solution 0, 4, 8 has minimal gap length of 2. So between those two the one with highest minimal gap is the optimal one.

Comment: @SmartK8 Ah, that makes sense now. It's a little trickier to keep track of as the MinGap and Gaps constraints conflict. I tried to explain why in some comments so hopefully it is clear, but basically you sometimes need to track two possible subsolutions. I'm pretty confident now that this satisfies both the constraints, *Phew!*